# How to get div to render on top of an image?

Tags: html, css, css-position

How can I make a horizontal bar of image links to render over an image? Like this:
[image: Header image with horizontal bar of image links across it]

Each icon should redirect to its corresponding page, and the header image itself is a .svg so whitespace doesn't render => I don't think z-index will be necessary

Comment: just post the code whatever you have tried

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i think you intended to do is to position the links on top of the background image.
So i prepared this small example.

Also, it's a good idea to add some kind of visual feedback when the user hovers the icons that he will understand that they are clickable :)

```css
.background {
  position: relative;
}
.links {
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 50px;
}
.links li {
  display: inline;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a img {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
a:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <img src="http://rockstartemplate.com/blogheaders/bannerdesign1.jpg">

  <ul class="links">
    <li>
      <a href="www.twitter.com">
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logotypes/32/twitter-48.png">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="www.facebook.com">
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logotypes/32/square-facebook-48.png">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="www.youtube.com">
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logotypes/32/youtube-48.png">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```